# WordPress settings API error when checkbox unchecked

Tags: theme-development, errors, theme-options, admin-menu

I am trying to creating some custom options for a template I am developing but I am getting an error when the checkbox (Line 130) is unchecked:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'show_admin_dev' in E:\composite-cms\WordPress-Settings-Sandbox-master\lib\admin\pages\dev-page.php on line 11

This is the line that seems to be throwing the error:

```
if ( $options['show_admin_dev'] == 1 )
```

The entire code can be found [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/4384579).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't included a sanitization function as the third parameter to register_settings on line 111. When no sanitization provided WordPress deletes the value of the option and creates a new one based **only** on what is passed in `$_POST`. Since unchecked checkboxes are not sent by the browser at all you end up with `$options['show_admin_dev']` being not set.

You should try to add sanitization which adds the value if it is not in the option

```
register_setting(
  'ccms_developer_options',
  'ccms_developer_options',
  'ccms_developer_sanit' 
);

function ccms_developer_sanit($newval) {
  if (!isset($newval['show_admin_dev'])) 
    $newval['show_admin_dev'] = 0;

  return $newval;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed that issue, in short i was being a dumdum.

Comment: nah, I think the setting API is not intuative. Too easy to miss an important detail and it is harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `$options['show_admin_dev']` is actually a *string*, not an integer. You're trying to compare a string to an integer, which really annoys newer versions of PHP.

When setting the default option (line 69), you have `show_admin_dev` set to `'0'`. Removing the quotes around this should prevent the error.

You can also convert `$options['show_admin_dev']` to an integer in the comparison using the [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/function.intval.php) function:

```
if ( intval( $options['show_admin_dev'] ) == 1 )
```